# Lightroom CC says it can migrate a Lightroom 6 catalog only once - why?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-catalog

I try to move one of my LR 6 catalogs to the newfangled LR CC. I get the following dialog:

[image: LR dialog]

Why can I migrate *only once*? I am planning to do a test migration and then later with a new CC library a proper migration.

And is there a way to re-do the migration later despite Adobe's warning?

Answer (score 1):

This is not warning, but required action because LR Classic work with new/updated format of catalogs. And AFAIK you can't avoid this action and skip the step. You can continue to use LR 2015 with old format of catalog. But if you need LR Classic you must migrate the catalog.

And you can migrate only once because after the migration the catalog will be in new format you do not need/can't be migrated. To play with this migration you can create new catalog with few images inside and do the test.

From what I remember during last convert I did convertor actually create new catalog and copy there the data from original catalog. But I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: Sorry @Romeo Ninov, I propbably wasn't clear enough. My question is: Why can I migrate only once? (Because I am planning to do a test migration from the 6 catalog to teh CC catalog and then later with a new CC catalog a proper migration.) So Why can I migrate only once?

Comment: @halloleo, check my edited answer

Comment: thanks. Does this mean LR CC *changes* the old catalog and uses it in the same location then onwards???

Comment: @halloleo, as I mention in the answer AFAIK it create new catalog, in new directory and keep the old one. But last convert I did was long time a go and I can't be 100% sure :)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wondering: If LR CC writes the photos to a new location why can't I import the old library later on again (after I have cleaned out all my tests in the new location)? That's how I understand this sentence "*Once a catalog is migrated it cannot be migrated it again.*"

Comment: @halloleo, LR do not touch your photos! The catalog is database with settings, your edits, other meta information.

Comment: Sure, but why can't I migrate the LR 6 catalog again into a new clean LR CC catalog? That's my question...

Comment: @halloleo, I can't get the reason why you need second convert. You have already converted the database. You can create a copy of your LR 6 catalog to new one. And do the second convert

Comment: Well, that's what I probably will do.... So it means the migration *can* be done mutiple times, right?

Comment: @halloleo, if you as on this way: Yes, it can be :)